# how to hide a recyclerview when another scrolls

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

hello I'm trying to implement 2 recycler view in one layout, one is horizontal on the top of the layout and below that is the second which is vertical, what I want is when the vertical recycler view scrolls the horizontal will remain hide until the vertical comes back to the starting position

Here is a solution i tried but there is an issue where animation is kind of wierd where the first scroll is laggy (sory i dindt find a good word to describe it) where after scrolling the first item then its back to normal and smoth and also after scrolling first item if scroll back to the top it dosent scrolls completly to the top only till the first item

here is a [Screen Recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18uYWwW5Ol7JujDvFbX5PnipHgQwdyyMX/view?usp=sharing) of the issue

```
 verticalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull @NotNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                    horizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view_all.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    if (!(horizontalRecyclerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)) {
                        horizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        view_all.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

here is my code

**fragment_home.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_all_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/view_all"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!--    Horizontal RecyclerView-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/postRecyclerView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_all_text"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:reverseLayout="true" />
    <!--    Vertical RecyclerView-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/postRecyclerView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

    <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shimmerEffect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <include layout="@layout/post_item_container_shimmer_home" />

        <include layout="@layout/post_item_container_shimmer_home" />


    </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**post_item_container_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/Card_View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam">

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePostHome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Card_View"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome">


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
postRecyclerView1.Visiblity=View.gone
recyclerViewHome.Visiblity=View.visible
```

if you want to show recycler view home then use above code

else use below

```
postRecyclerView1.Visiblity=View.visible

recyclerViewHome.Visiblity=View.gone
```

Comment: ok but how do implement it when scroll take place

Answer (score 1):

here you add onScrollListener to your vertical recycler view and override method onScrolled(). More information you can go to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener#onScrolled(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,%20int,%20int)).
Example implementation to help you:

```
verticalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull @NotNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            //set the visibility of honrizontalRecyclerView base on whether we can scroll upwards (-1 indicates upwards)
           if(recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)) 
             honrizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(Visibility.GONE);
           else 
           {
             if(!honrizontalRecyclerView.isVisible())
               honrizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i think this will work but there is an error it says required int and provided bollean when passing(-1)

Comment: oh that is my mistake, I have edited to post

Comment: thank you so much for the answer , i have a liite issue if you can solve it the scroll is very lagy or i say its not smoth ,is there any solution to it

Comment: How lag it it is? What information each item contains? Does it happen before adding my answer?

Comment: before implementing your method  the recylerview dosent hides up but the vertical one was very smoth

Comment: it should because we check and set visibility too often (while scrolling). Try adding a if condition to check the visibility of the horizontal view and set it visible only when it doesn't

Comment: can you provide the code if it possible for you , becuase i tried but it dosent work ,the scroll is not smoth only for the first item but after first item is scrolled rest of them are smoth BTW i forgot to mention that i implemnt one item scroll at a time .

Comment: please see my update code snippet. Did you do that?

Comment: nope it dosent work i have updated the code please check the java part

Comment: here is a screen recording of my app https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s6_ziCtfMMinDjgiUYx7rJnckUsRkmfx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry but I dont it lag as you say. We dont use any animation here so the effect quite not good

Comment: what kind of animation should i use can you suggest me anything about it ,sorry for the late reply

Comment: just add some simple animation when you hide or show. Take a look at this [article](https://findnerd.com/list/view/HideShow-a-View-with-slide-updown-animation-in-Android/2537/) and see if it helps